# vs code auto format on save disable for react

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code

when I trying to learn react
I use vs code as a editor

but when I save files, VS code change code format and it give a error
eg:[before save](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P0M5u.jpg)

[after save](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e4XZJ.jpg)

I already tried disable `formatOnSave` on vs code
but it did not work
[disable `formatOnSave` on vs code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S50d6.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

create a folder named `.vscode` and create a file inside it, named `settings.json`. (`.vscode/settings.json`)

and paste this code over there

```json
{
    "[javascript]": {
        "editor.formatOnSave": false
    },
    "[typescript]": {
        "editor.formatOnSave": false
    }
}
```

maybe this will help.

Comment: thank you for ans.
but it did not work

Comment: can you try to restart your vscode, and can you please tell me what is your file extension? `.js` or `.jsx` ?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your file has a language mode of javascriptreact ... ,that is, go to the right botton corner of VScode and change language from Javascript to Javascript_react. And better change your file extension from .js into .jsx

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer . Good luck